# Applying a call only once in a recursive method in SCHEME

Tags: scheme

I have this method I wrote

```
(define (lev n L)
  ;(set! L(apply append L))
  (cond ((null? L) '())
        ((eq? n (car (car L))) (car L))
        (else (lev n (cdr L)))))
```

I want to apply the 'set!' only once before recursion and be done with it. I can't think of how to do this.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: What are you aiming to do? What have you tried? How has what you've tried differed from what you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (lev n L)
  (let loop ((L (apply append L)))
    (cond ((null? L) '())
          ((eq? n (car (car L))) (car L))
          (else (loop (cdr L))))))
```

Here we're using a [named `let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29) for defining a helper procedure inside `lev` (in this example, it's called `loop`), and before calling it we apply `append` to the input list and assign it to a new variable, also called `L`. In this case it's not necessary to use `set!`, in idiomatic Scheme we tend to avoid mutation operations.

Comment: It's the great Oscar lopez :) So Im getting this error using that The procedure #[compound-procedure 15 loop] has been called with 2 arguments; it requires exactly 1 argument

Comment: I'm doing (lev 'b L) where L is  (((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) ((d 4) (e 5) (f 6)))

Comment: I've since found another way to do this, but I wanted to know why I'm getting that error I don't understand

Comment: @Crowlands it was my mistake, when we call `loop`, only a single parameter is required (the `n` is the same from `lev`, because it doesn't change during the iteration). It's fixed now :)